# Globally set time unit and use wall-clock time when using google benchmark library?

Tags: c++, google-benchmark

I'm using google benchmark library for my own program time cost measuring.

I found my program time cost is milliseconds level, but benchmark's default time unit is nanosecond.

Also, many of them are with multi-thread inside so I prefer real-time (wall-clock time) instead of the default one, the main thread's CPU time.

For one specific benchmark test, I can write it as :

```cpp
BENCHMARK_REGISTER_F(AreaResizeFast_Fixture, tv)->Unit(benchmark::kMillisecond)->UseRealTime();
```

Question: is it possible globally using milliseconds and real-time, i.e. config them once and use it always?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to set the time unit globally now according to this [PR](https://github.com/google/benchmark/pull/1337).

The latest version of the [user guide](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/main/docs/user_guide.md#setting-the-time-unit) may help.